# Calling RabbitMQ from Nodejs (Docker)

Tags: node.js, docker, rabbitmq, microservices

I'm trying to connect rabbitMQ to another service, and I'm getting this error:

[image]

composer:

[image]

Code:

[image]

Comment: Try to log `err` object, it must be more descriptive

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for late response, Maybe you can share your bridging configuration because both rabbitMQ and app